# Comparing two equatable values - "Could not find overload for '==' that accepts the supplied argument"

Tags: swift

I am getting the following error when comparing elem to value in the code below

```
Could not find overload for '==' that accepts the supplied argument


func indexOf(array: AnyObject[], value: AnyObject) -> Int? {
    for (index, elem) in enumerate(array) {
        if elem == value  {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have also tried Equatable and still getting the same error

```
    func indexOf(array: Array<Equatable>, value: Equatable) -> Int? {
        for (index, elem : Equatable) in enumerate(array) {
            if elem as Equatable == value as Equatable {
                return index
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` operator requires arguments of type `Equatable` (a *protocol*).  You've declared the argument type as `AnyObject` which is not `Equatable`.  Hence the compiler error.

Here is the implementation from the Apple documentation on Swift (page 27):

```
func findIndex<T: Equatable>(array: T[], valueToFind: T) -> Int? {
    for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        if value == valueToFind {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it actually be generic, such that `array` is an array of the same equatable type as `value`? Otherwise you might be comparing values of different types, which is not allowed, right?

Comment: Right, I updated the answer (before your comment, coincidentally).  The type `T` is now identical between the value and the array contents.